# Добавление данных в таблицу связывания "многие ко многим"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

При помощи Entity Fremework Code First сгенерированы таблицы `AspNetUsers` (стандартная таблица ASP.NET Identity) и `GaveBooks` со связью многие ко многим:
[image: диаграмма].

EF автоматически сгенерировал таблицу связи `GaveBookApplicationUsers`. Задача - записать в таблицу выданных книг `GaveBookApplicationUsers` пользователя, которому она выдана. Просто добавить книгу в таблицу `GaveBook` получается, а вот указать в таблице `GaveBookApplicationUsers` какая книга кому отдана не получилось. Вот мой код:

```
 using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
            {

                var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(givenBook.Email);

                GaveBook gaveBook = new GaveBook
                {
                    ReturnDate = givenBook.DateReturn,
                    BookId = givenBook.BookId,
                };

                user.GaveBooks.Add(gaveBook);
                db.GaveBooks.Add(gaveBook);
                db.SaveChanges();
           }
```

`UserManager - объект`ApplicationUserManager`, который возвращает всех пользователей.
Вот так выглядит класс ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }
        public virtual ICollection<GaveBook> GaveBooks { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BookingBook> BookingBooks { get; set; }

    }
```

И GaveBook

```
 public class GaveBook
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public virtual Book Book { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: покажите класс создающий связь многие ко многим?есть ли у него виртуальные свойства?

Comment: Добавил описание классов сущностей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, при работе с таблицами производными от ASP.NET Identity для обновления данных необходимо пользоваться специальным методом Update, который нужно вызывать на классе менеджера пользователей. Следующий код добавляет запись и в GaveBooks, и в GaveBookApplicationUsers, что и требовалось сделать.

```
user.GaveBooks = new List<GaveBook>() { gaveBook };
UserManager.Update(user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить вызов SaveChanges в конце вашего кода:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
{
    // ...
    user.GaveBooks.Add(gaveBook);
    db.GaveBooks.Add(gaveBook);
    db.SaveChanges(); // <-- HERE
}
```

Comment: Он у меня и так там стоит - в код случайно не включил... Код поправил, спасибо. Данные в GaveBook, как я писал ранее, добавляются, а вот в таблицу связывания - нет(

Answer (score 0):

а если попробовать так:

```
var user=db.Users.First();
var book=db.Books.First();
book.Users.Add(book) or user.Books.Add(user)//выдаем книгу пользователю
db.SaveChanges();
```

вроде должно работать.

Comment: пробовал так:
`var user=db.Users.First(); var book=db.GaveBooks.First(); book.ApplicationUsers.Add(user); db.SaveChanges();`
и наоборот. Данные ни в одну из таблиц не добавились.

Comment: Gave это возврат, GaveBookApplicationUser связь между возвратом и пользователем?а нужна ли здесь связь many-to-many?разве одна книга может быть выдана нескольким пользователям?может стоит пересмотреть схему БД?

Comment: Есть три таблицы: таблица книг Books, таблица выданных книг GaveBooks и таблица пользователей ApplicationUsers. Одна книга может быть выдана одному пользователю - связь "один ко многим" между Books и GaveBooks; пользователи могут взять себе несколько книг - связь "многие ко многим" между GaveBooks и ApplicationUsers.

Comment: а что мешает добавить поле UserId в таблицу GaveBooks. одна книга выдана одному пользователю.что мешает выдать вторую книгу этому же пользователю?!

Comment: Да, действительно, Вы правы, здесь правильной будет связь "один ко многим", спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationContext()
{
    //..
    user.GaveBooks.Add(gaveBook);    

    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/5.10.php
должно сработать)